# Redefine object inside a loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following working example you can see a square consisting of 4 squared objects. I like to know how to define the compound square as a new command which I can use at next iteration inside the loop?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\wuerfel}[3][]{%
    \begin{scope}[rotate=#1,shift={(#2,#3)}]
        \draw[fill=red!20, very thin] (0,0) rectangle (.5,.5);%
        \draw [step=.5, very thin] (0,0) grid (1,1);%
    \end{scope}
}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,0}{
    %\let\oldwuerfel\wuerfel
        \wuerfel[0]{\i}{\i};
        \wuerfel[90]{\i+1}{\i-1};
        \wuerfel[0]{\i+1}{\i+1};
        \wuerfel[-90]{\i-1}{\i+1};
        %\renewcommand*{\wuerfel}[1][]{%
        %   \oldwuerfel[0]{#1}{#1};
        %   \oldwuerfel[90]{#1+1}{#1-1};
        %   \oldwuerfel[0]{#1+1}{#1+1};
        %   \oldwuerfel[-90]{#1-1}{#1+1};
        %   }%
    %\wuerfel[\i]{}{};
    }%      

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you explain more what result you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using a box to save the objects.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\Wuerfellist{}

\newsavebox{\Wuerfel}
\sbox{\Wuerfel}{%
  \tikz{
    \useasboundingbox(0,0)rectangle(1,1);
    \fill[blue!20] (0,0) rectangle (.5,.5);
    \draw [step=.5, very thin] (0,0) grid (1,1);
}}

\newcommand*\mehrereWuerfel[1]{{%
  \def\Wuerfellist{}%
  \foreach[count=\j from 0] \i in {1,...,#1}{\listxadd{\Wuerfellist}{\j}}%
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{%
    \sbox{\Wuerfel}{%
      \tikz[nodes={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=south west}]{
        \node{\usebox\Wuerfel};
        \begin{scope}[shift={({2^##1},{2^##1})}]
          \node[rotate=90]{\usebox\Wuerfel};
          \node{\usebox\Wuerfel};
          \node[rotate=-90]{\usebox\Wuerfel};
        \end{scope}
  }}}%
  \dolistloop{\Wuerfellist}%
  \usebox\Wuerfel%
}}

\begin{document}
\usebox\Wuerfel \hfill \mehrereWuerfel{1} \hfill \mehrereWuerfel{2}

\bigskip
\mehrereWuerfel{1}\hfill\mehrereWuerfel{3}

\bigskip
\scalebox{.25}{\mehrereWuerfel{6}}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]